# Is there a way to convert huge vector of type integer (only contain 0 and 1) to bit in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, memory, memory-management, rscript

I have a huge data-frame. One column is the class Integer. The column has only 0 and 1 as values. This is taking a lot of RAM. Is there a way I can reduce the memory consumption here? I was thinking if there is a possible way I can convert the integer values into bit values. The size occupied by 1L is 48 bytes, but '1' as a bit will consume only 1 bit? I am not sure. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I thought converting to `logical` might help with this but it does not seem to: logical still allows `NA` values so cannot just be a single bit per value.

Comment: Yea, I have checked that, and logical value takes 48 bytes too.

Comment: Check out `bit` package: `set.seed(42); x = sample(0:1, 10000, TRUE); object.size(x); library(bit); y = as.bit(x); object.size(y)`

Comment: @d.b I have tried doing that but the size of the previous dataframe and the new one is not so different 96mb to 92mb. From your example when I did object.size(x[1]) outputs 48 bytes and object.size(y[1]) it outputs 256 bytes. But still object.size(x) is significantly larger than object.size(y). I'm confused, how is that possible? more yet, why is my dataframe still nearly the same size?

Comment: Maybe try converting to raw with the `as.raw()` function. This might reduce your size by 1/4.